# Amazon AWS Simple Workflow Service SWF PHP Samples

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I was wondering if there are any SWF workflow PHP sample code available for the AWS PHPSDK 2+ ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I looked for a tutorial and wasn't able to find one.  Eventually, I went through the docs and examples using Ruby and the web API and pieced together the nuts and bolts of working with the PHP SDK.

The first thing you need to do is register your domain, workflow, and activities.  This can be done either through the AWS console or using the PHP SDK.  Using the SDK, use the following:

```
<?php

require_once "path/to/aws.phar";

use Aws\Swf\SwfClient;

// Create an instance of the SWF class
$client = SwfClient::factory(array(
    "key" => "your_aws_key",
    "secret" => "your_aws_secret_key",
    "region" => "your_aws_region"
));

// Register your domain
$client->registerDomain(array(
    "name" => "domain name you want",
    "description" => "this is a test domain",
    "workflowExecutionRetentionPeriodInDays" => "7"
));

// Register your workflow
$client->registerWorkflowType(array(
    "domain" => "domain name you registered in previous call",
    "name" => "workflow name you want",
    "version" => "1.0",
    "description" => "this is a sample",
    "defaultTaskList" => array(
        "name" => "mainTaskList"
    ),
    "defaultChildPolicy" => "TERMINATE"
));

// Register an activity
$client->registerActivityType(array(
    "domain" => "domain name you registered above",
    "name" => "activity name you want",
    "version" => "1.0",
    "description" => "first activity in our workflow",
    "defaultTaskList" => array(
        "name" => "mainTaskList"
    )
));

// Follow activity registration example above and register 
// more activities as you wish
```

The next step is to create a decider.  This is the script that acts as the coordinating node for your activity (worker) nodes.

```
// Ask SWF for things the decider needs to know
$result = $client->pollForDecisionTask(array(
    "domain" => "your domain name",
    "taskList" => array(
        "name" => "mainTaskList"
    ),
    "identify" => "default",
    "maximumPageSize" => 50,
    "reverseOrder" => true
));

// Current version of activity types we are using
$activity_type_version = "1.0";

// Parse info we need returned from the pollForDecisionTask call
$task_token = $result["taskToken"];
$workflow_id = $result["workflowExecution"]["workflowId"];
$run_id = $result["workflowExecution"]["runId"];
$last_event = $result["events"][0]["eventId"];

// Our logic that decides what happens next
if($last_event == "3"){
    $activity_type_name = "activity to start if last event ID was 3";
    $task_list = "mainTaskList";
    $activity_id = "1";
    $continue_workflow = true;
}
elseif($last_event == "8"){
    $activity_type_name = "activity to start if last event ID was 8";
    $task_list = "mainTaskList";
    $activity_id = "2";
    $continue_workflow = false;
}

// Now that we populated our variables based on what we received 
// from SWF, we need to tell SWF what we want to do next
if($continue_workflow === true){
    $client->respondDecisionTaskCompleted(array(
        "taskToken" => $task_token,
        "decisions" => array(
            array(
                "decisionType" => "ScheduleActivityTask",
                "scheduleActivityTaskDecisionAttributes" => array(
                    "activityType" => array(
                        "name" => $activity_type_name,
                        "version" => $activity_type_version
                    ),
                    "activityId" => $activity_id,
                    "control" => "this is a sample message",
                    // Customize timeout values
                    "scheduleToCloseTimeout" => "360",
                    "scheduleToStartTimeout" => "300",
                    "startToCloseTimeout" => "60",
                    "heartbeatTimeout" => "60",
                    "taskList" => array(
                        "name" => $task_list
                    ),
                    "input" => "this is a sample message"
                )
            )
        )
    ));
}
// End workflow if last event ID was 8
else if($continue_workflow === false){
    $client->respondDecisionTaskCompleted(array(
        "taskToken" => $task_token,
        "decisions" => array(
            array(
                "decisionType" => "CompleteWorkflowExecution"
            )
        )
    ));
}
```

The final step is to create your activity workers.  You can spin them up using the following format:

```
// Check with SWF for activities
$result = $client->pollForActivityTask(array(
    "domain" => "domain name you registered",
    "taskList" => array(
        "name" => "mainTaskList"
    )
));

// Take out task token from the response above
$task_token = $result["taskToken"];

// Do things on the computer that this script is saved on
exec("my program i want to execute");

// Tell SWF that we finished what we need to do on this node
$client->respondActivityTaskCompleted(array(
    "taskToken" => $task_token,
    "result" => "I've finished!"
));
```

The scripts for your activity workers and decider can be put on any server.  These scripts all call SWF in order to communicate with each other.

Finally, to start the workflow you just created, use:

```
// Generate a random workflow ID
$workflowId = mt_rand(1000, 9999);

// Starts a new instance of our workflow
$client->startWorkflowExecution(array(
    "domain" => "your domain name",
    "workflowId" => $workflowId,
    "workflowType" => array(
        "name" => "your workflow name",
        "version" => "1.0"
    ),
    "taskList" => array(
        "name" => "mainTaskList"
    ),
    "input" => "a message goes here",
    "executionStartToCloseTimeout" => "300",
    'taskStartToCloseTimeout' => "300",
    "childPolicy" => "TERMINATE"
));
```

Comment: So how did swf work for you overall? Recommend? See where I'm coming from here https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/3034/4997

Answer (score 1):

Based on the posts above, I was able to create a fully functioning workflow that is really easy to modify for your purposes.Thanks guys. After installing the AWS PHP SDK with composer, assigning the correct file paths, and setting up your Domain, Workflow Type, and Activity Types in the console (which is really easy), you can use the scripts below to execute a flow in sequence. I was able to execute them myself before posting this. Running ExecuteFlow.php once everything is set up should be all that's required!

The 8 scripts are posted here (don't worry, 3 are very short):

ExecuteFlow.php :

```
<?php 
//This script is used to begin a new workflow then activate the decider and workers to finish the job.
// 
//SWF scripts originally developed by ~ in April, 2018 based on the first comment in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765377/amazon-aws-simple-workflow-service-swf-php-samples
//
//PROGRAMMER MODIFICATIONS sections are for updates to the Steps in Workflow, the rest of SWF Workflow should be automated with these scripts.
//
// Command Reference: 
//
// https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-swf-2012-01-25.html 
//
// For Reference: 
//          Workflow Type (Name) is MainWorkflow
//          Activity Type (Names) are Step 1, Step 2, and Step 3
//    Task List for MainWorkflow is MainTaskList
//           Task List for Step 1 is TaskList1, Step 2 is TaskList2, etc.
//
//
//Software Required:
//
//Installed AWS PHP SDK
//ExecuteFlow.php
//Decider.php
//Worker.php
//DescribeExecution.php
//TerminateFlow.php
//Test.php
//Test2.php
//Test3.php



//Once it's installed using composer, this accesses the PHP AWS SDK
require_once "PHP-AWS-SDK/autoload.php";


//This grabs the client from the SDK so we can use it to do our SWF bidding.
//(Note: the version should stay synonymous with the currently packaged SDK version so it works with our code.)
$client = new Aws\Swf\SwfClient([
    'version' => '2012-01-25',
    'region'  => 'us-east-1' 
    ]);



//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------------PROGRAMMER MODIFICATIONS--------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Variables that we want to carry through the workflow
$Domain_Name='MyDomainName';
$Activity_Type_Version = "1";
$Workflow_Task_List_Name="MainTaskList";
$TotalNumberofSteps=3;
$TimeAllottedforEachStep="300"; //seconds

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------



//Clear the way for a new workflow


//How many workflows are open?
$result = $client->countOpenWorkflowExecutions([
    'domain' => $Domain_Name, 
    'startTimeFilter' => [
        'oldestDate' => 1524755000,
    ],
]);

$OpenWorkflowCount=$result["count"];


if ($OpenWorkflowCount <> 0){

//This loop terminates all the current workflows 
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $OpenWorkflowCount; $x++) {


$result = $client->listOpenWorkflowExecutions([
    'domain' => $Domain_Name, 
    'startTimeFilter' => [
        'oldestDate' => 1524755000,
    ],
]);

$OpenWorkflowID = $result["executionInfos"][0]["execution"]["workflowId"];
echo "You have an open workflow: $OpenWorkflowID.\n\n";
$WorkflowID=$OpenWorkflowID;
echo "Terminating Workflow $OpenWorkflowID...\n";
$Run_ID=$result["executionInfos"][0]["execution"]["runId"];
$Reason="Flow was terminated to clear the way for a new Workflow";
require 'TerminateFlow.php';

}

}



// Execution of the workflow begins now-----------------------------------------

// Generate a random workflow ID
$WorkflowID = mt_rand(1000, 9999);

//Turn it into a string for input to SWF
settype($WorkflowID,"string");


echo "\nRandomly Generated Workflow ID is ".$WorkflowID."\n";


//Let's get this party started.
$client->startWorkflowExecution([
    'domain' => $Domain_Name,
    'workflowId' => $WorkflowID,
    'workflowType' => [
        'name' => 'MainWorkflow',
        'version' => '1'
        ],
    'taskList' => [
        'name' => $Workflow_Task_List_Name
        ], 
    'input' => 'Starting a Workflow',
    //'executionStartToCloseTimeout' => '300',
   // 'taskStartToCloseTimeout' => '300',
   // 'childPolicy' => 'TERMINATE',
]);


echo "The workflow is now being executed!\n\n";
//echo "\nLet's ask the decider what to do next:\n";
require 'Decider.php';


//Here we will confirm completion of the workflow

 echo "Verifying Completion: \n";

$result = $client->describeWorkflowExecution([
    'domain' => $Domain_Name, 
    'execution' => [ 
        'runId' => $Run_ID,
        'workflowId' => $Workflow_ID,
    ],
]);


 $Finished = $result["executionInfo"]["closeStatus"];


 if ($Finished == 'COMPLETED')
 {
 echo "$Finished \nWe have completed the workflow!\n";
 }

 else {
  echo "$Finished \nCheck on your application.\n";
 }


 //This is the amount of time it took to run the workflow

  $WorkflowStartTimestamp=$result["executionInfo"]["startTimestamp"];
 $WorkflowEndTimestamp=$result["executionInfo"]["closeTimestamp"];
 $wfinterval = $WorkflowStartTimestamp->diff($WorkflowEndTimestamp);
    $m=$wfinterval->format('%i minute(s)');
    $s=$wfinterval->format('%s second(s)');

    echo "Running time: $m $s.\n\n";

?>
```

Decider.php :

```
<?php

//DECIDER




// What's on the agenda today boss?
$result = $client->pollForDecisionTask(array(
    "domain" => $Domain_Name,
    "taskList" => array(
        "name" => $Workflow_Task_List_Name
    ),
     "identity" => "Decider is choosing whether to continue or end the workflow",
    // "maximumPageSize" => 50,
    "reverseOrder" => true //This makes sure the events are returned in reverse order. It makes it easier to tell which event is current/most recent (helps generate $WorkflowEventID variable below).
));



// Parse info we need returned from the pollForDecisionTask call
$task_token = $result["taskToken"];
$Workflow_ID = $result["workflowExecution"]["workflowId"];
$Run_ID=$result["workflowExecution"]["runId"];
$WorkflowEventID = $result["events"][0]["eventId"];


// Our logic that decides what happens next...
//If we have x steps, we will need 3+x*6 WorkflowEventID's before sending the command to end the workflow.
//Here's where this is automatically calculated:
$CalculatedEventID=3+$TotalNumberofSteps*6;


//Below, we decide on whether to continue the workflow.
//It would be simpler to skip this section and only modify the section below, but 
//it allows us to avoid redundancy (for example, "require 'Worker.php';" below).

if($WorkflowEventID < $CalculatedEventID){
    $task_list = $Workflow_Task_List_Name;
    $continue_workflow = true;
}

elseif($WorkflowEventID == $CalculatedEventID){
    $task_list = $Workflow_Task_List_Name;
    $continue_workflow = false;
}





//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------------PROGRAMMER MODIFICATIONS--------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Now that we populated our variables based on what we received 
// from SWF, we need to tell SWF what we want to do next

// These loops assign variables the appropriate names/values for each Step based
//on the Event ID we're on. These variables are carried through to the worker.
//Variable values should be synonymous with the activity types in the SWF console.


if($continue_workflow === true){

 //Decider STEP 1---------------------------------------------------------------
    if ($WorkflowEventID == "3")

 {$Step = "Step 1";
     $Activity_Task_List_Name = "TaskList1";
     $Activity_ID = "1";
    // echo "The decider says its current Workflow ID is ".$Workflow_ID."\n\n";
 }


 //Decider STEP 2---------------------------------------------------------------  
    elseif ($WorkflowEventID == "9")

 {$Step = "Step 2";
    $Activity_ID = "2";
     $Activity_Task_List_Name = "TaskList2";
 }  

  //Decider STEP 3--------------------------------------------------------------
    elseif ($WorkflowEventID == "15")

 {$Step = "Step 3";
    $Activity_ID = "3";
     $Activity_Task_List_Name = "TaskList3";
 }  

else 
{echo "Something's Fishy\n\n";}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------




//We mark the Decision Task Complete before moving to the Worker

   $client->respondDecisionTaskCompleted(array(
        "taskToken" => $task_token,
        "decisions" => array(
            array(
                "decisionType" => "ScheduleActivityTask",
                "scheduleActivityTaskDecisionAttributes" => array(
                    "activityType" => array(
                        "name" => $Step,
                        "version" => $Activity_Type_Version
                    ),
                    "activityId" => $Activity_ID,
                    "control" => "Have a great day!",
                    // Customize timeout values
                    //"scheduleToCloseTimeout" => "360",
                    //"scheduleToStartTimeout" => "300",
                    "startToCloseTimeout" => $TimeAllottedforEachStep,
                    //"heartbeatTimeout" => "60",
                    "taskList" => array(
                        "name" => $Workflow_Task_List_Name
                    ),
                    "input" => "$Step Assigned to Worker"
                )
            )
        )
    ));


//Here we have the worker do the decider's bidding. 
     require 'Worker.php';




//The Timestamp stuff and response here can also be placed at the end of the worker script.
//They are placed here to simplify the worker script since the decider is 
//really supposed to be doing all the 'non-executing stuff' stuff. 


    $ReverseDescribeorNot=False;
    require 'DescribeExecution.php';

    $TimestampStart = $result["events"][$WorkflowEventID]["eventTimestamp"];
    $TimestampEnd   = $result["events"][$WorkflowEventID+4]["eventTimestamp"];
    $interval = $TimestampStart->diff($TimestampEnd);
    $m=$interval->format('%i minute(s)');
    $s=$interval->format('%s second(s)');


    echo $Step."/".$TotalNumberofSteps." completed in $m $s.\n\n";






 //We require the Decider here because if we do so in the Worker script, the worker script is unable to finish before being executed again above. 
 //This allows the Decider to loop back up to the top and figure out where it's at in the workflow and decide from there. 
 //Although it puts the Decider into a loop of itself, the if statements make sure it executes the correct things based on its feeback from SWF.
     require 'Decider.php';


}



// End workflow if last event ID was the final WorkflowEventID
else if($continue_workflow === false){
    $client->respondDecisionTaskCompleted(array(
        "taskToken" => $task_token,
        "decisions" => array(

            array(
                "decisionType" => "CompleteWorkflowExecution",

            ),
        )
    ));
}


?>
```

Worker.php :

```
<?php

//WORKER


//Typically, for SWF, a worker is a service, script, or person that performs a specific function. 
//For our purposes, all our workers are php scripts.
//Therefore, in order to avoid redundancy, we simply use this single script to activate our workers.
//Because developers don't want to worry about putting a "pollForActivityTask" and "respondActivityTaskCompleted" call in each of their scripts,
//we simply make those calls here and execute each script when SWF is ready for it. 


//echo "\nNow, the worker is working.\n\n";



// Check with SWF for activities
$result = $client->pollForActivityTask([
    "domain" => "Cloud Optimization",
    "taskList" => [
        "name" => $Workflow_Task_List_Name
    ]
]);


// Take out task token from the response above

$task_token = $result["taskToken"];




//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------------PROGRAMMER MODIFICATIONS--------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This is where the Worker actually executes activities

//Worker STEP 1-----------------------------------------------------------------
if ($Step == 'Step 1') {

require 'Test.php';

}

//Worker STEP 2-----------------------------------------------------------------
elseif ($Step == 'Step 2') {

require 'Test2.php';
}


//Worker STEP 3-----------------------------------------------------------------
elseif ($Step == 'Step 3') {
require 'Test3.php';
}

else 
{echo "Something's Super Duper Fishy\n\n";}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------



 //If the Activity Timed out, we'll find out here before our app explodes

 //This grabs the eventType statement associated with the current Workflow EventID

 $ReverseDescribeorNot=True;
 require 'DescribeExecution.php';
 $MightHaveTimedOut = $result["events"][1]["eventType"];



if ($MightHaveTimedOut == "ActivityTaskTimedOut")
{
    echo "\n$Step Timed Out, Cancelling Workflow...\n";
    $Reason="$Step Activity Timed Out";
    require 'TerminateFlow.php';
    exit;
}

else {

    $ResultResponse=$Step."/".$TotalNumberofSteps." completed.";
// Tell SWF that we finished what we need to do on this node
$client->respondActivityTaskCompleted(array(
    "taskToken" => $task_token,
    "result" => $ResultResponse
));


}


//echo "\nAaand now back to the decider.\n";


?>
```

TerminateFlow.php :

```
<?php

$result = $client->terminateWorkflowExecution([
    'childPolicy' => 'TERMINATE',
    'details' => $Reason,
    'domain' => $Domain_Name, // REQUIRED
    'reason' => $Reason,
    'runId' => $Run_ID,
    'workflowId' => $WorkflowID, // REQUIRED
]);

echo "Workflow $WorkflowID Terminated\n\n";

?>
```

DescribeExecution :

```
<?php



// echo "\n\nExecution History:\n\n";

$result = $client->getWorkflowExecutionHistory([
    'domain' => $Domain_Name, 
    'execution' => [ 
        'runId' => $Run_ID,
        'workflowId' => $Workflow_ID,
    ],

//     'maximumPageSize' => <integer>,
//   'nextPageToken' => '<string>',
    'reverseOrder' => $ReverseDescribeorNot,//true || false,
]);


?>
```

Test.php :

```
<?php

echo "Test.php is executing!\n";

?>
```

Test2.php :

```
<?php

echo "Test2.php is executing!\n";

?>
```

Test3.php :

```
<?php

echo "Test3.php is executing!\n";

?>
```

[Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLQqa.jpg)

As long as the scripts are in the same folder, file paths should not be an issue.
Good luck!