# Is the AWS SWF and SQS relationship similar to Celery and RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, amazon-sqs, amazon-swf

I need to know the actual difference between them. I just learned of these techs at the high level.

Answer (score 2):

No. AWS SWF is a workflow orchestration engine which has internal queueing support to deliver activity tasks. It is focused on coordinating execution of those tasks. SQS is a pure queue without any other additional features. 
My understanding is that RubbitMQ is more like SQS, just not as fault tolerant and scalable and Celery is just a Python client side library to consume from it.
AWS SWF provides its own client side libraries to consume from its internal queues (called task lists)

Comment: I'm running a laravel project that uses beanstalk queue, but we're struggling with that. I'm [considering](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/3034/4997) switching to SWF. However I noticed that the amazon folks only made a  wrapper library ([flow](https://aws.amazon.com/swf/details/flow/)) in ruby and java. To do things from scratch using php includes a lot of [ugliness and boilerplate code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27382798/766570).. I'm considering running it using ruby simply to speed dev velocity.. do you agree with that approach?

Comment: It sounds reasonable. You might also consider using Cadence (https://github.com/uber/cadence, which is open source analog of SWF) and its Go client side library.